# Excel VBA find a range of same values in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a macro that will find the cell range based on a value. A column will have the same value in a row, I need to find out what is the first and last column that has the same value in a row.[image]

So the macro needs to find that "Jill Cross" range is a4 to a9

So far I don't have much, got a way to find the first occurrence of a value

```
   Function GetFirstCell(CellRef As Range)
   Dim l As Long
   l = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CellRef.Value, Range("A1:A10000"), 0)
   GetFirstCell = l
   End Function
```

Now I need to loop through the next rows somehow to return the last row of an occurrence

Comment: Why do you need a macro for that, what's your ultimate goal?

Comment: I need to ultimately pass the start and end column to another function

Comment: You mean row? Can the rows with the same value not be contiguous, i.e. the list is not sorted?

Comment: Sorry yes row, the list is sorted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have your first cell in a sorted list, a countif function will give you the last cell easily.

```
   Function GetFirstCell(CellRef As Range) as long
       Dim l As Long
       l = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CellRef.Value, Range("A1:A10000"), 0)
       GetFirstCell = l
   End Function

   function GetLastCell(cellRef as range, lFirstCell as long)
       Dim l As Long
       l = Application.WorksheetFunction.countif(Range("A1:A10000"), CellRef.Value)
       GetLastCell = lFirstCell+l-1
   End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work though it has its limitations (for example if the names aren't sorted and the name you are looking for is separated across multiple places in your range...). Of course you need to replace the ranges with those you want to check and "bob" with whatever name you are looking for. Also, the column is static so you may want to alter that part. This is an array formula so you will need to press [ctrl]+[shift]+[enter] in the formula bar to execute it.

`="A"&MIN(IF(ROW(A1:A6)*(A1:A6="bob")=0, 99999999, ROW(A1:A6)*(A1:A6="bob")))&":A"&MAX(SI(ROW(A1:A6)*(A1:A6="bob")=0, -99999999, ROW(A1:A6)*(A1:A6="bob")))`